# Приведение типов в с#

Tags: c#

Как проходит процесс приведение типа в Program( то, что закомментировано-возвращает Null(пытаюсь понять логику))

```
namespace тренировка2
{
interface Iinterface
    {
        public void Show();
    }
class MyClass : MyClass1, Iinterface
    {
        private MyClass1 MyClass1;
        public MyClass1 Field1 
        {
            get { return MyClass1; }
            set { MyClass1 = value; }
        }
        override public string Field{
            get
            {
                if (field=="base")
                  return  "derived";
                else
                return field;
            }
        }
        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(field + " " + Field1.Field);
        }
        public MyClass(string field)
            :base(field)
{

}
    }
    class MyClass1
    {
        protected string field;
        public MyClass1(string field)
        {
            this.field = field;
        }
        virtual public string Field
        {
            set { field = value; }
            get { return field; }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass my = new MyClass("base");
            Console.WriteLine(my.Field);
            MyClass1 my1 = new MyClass1("base");
            Console.WriteLine(my1.Field);
            my.Field1 = new MyClass("base");
            //my = (MyClass)my.Field1;     //Что здесь происходит?
            my.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//my = (MyClass)my.Field1;     //Что здесь происходит?
```

Здесь происходит обращение к полю `MyClass.MyClass1`, которое нигде не назначается.

Comment: можно простыми словами, пожалуйста. Я создал экземпляр класса в классе.А что потом?

Comment: @левонхетрпов Вы не "создали", а "объявили" поле `MyClass1 MyClass1` в классе  `MyClass`. Такие поля по умолчанию инициализируются значением `null`.

Comment: мне кажется что разбирать этот пример - кощунство. если @левонхетрпов Вы хотите понять наследование - пожалуйста прочитайте про него подробнее и найдите более пригодные и информативные примеры. там же где и наследование, будет упоминаться приведение типов, в рамках наследования.

Comment: @левонхетрпов Никакого "приведения типов" здесь не нужно, так как переменная `my` и так `MyClass`.

Comment: @Igor в Program создаю. Вы немного раскрутили мысли в голове мне, но к умозаключению все равно не могу придти.

Comment: @левонхетрпов "в Program создаю" - на какой строчке?

Comment: @igor насчет второго не совсем понял, про экземпляр my понятно, про my.Filed1 нет

Comment: @левонхетрпов Я не успеваю за Вашими мыслями и не понимаю, что Вы хотите сказать.

Comment: @Igor разобрался)) я свойство использую для того чтобы экземпляры класса Myclass1 через MyClass создавать(что то такое получилось), спасибо за помощь

Comment: @левонхетрпов Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.